# laravel collective form - how to send id (foreign key) with form

Tags: forms, laravel

As in title how to do that? I have table comments, the structure of this table is:

-id 
-title 
-contents 
-user_id

Here is code of my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['LibraryController@newcomment', $sth->myuserid]]) !!}

        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null) !!}

        {!! Form::label('contents', 'Contents:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('contents', null) !!}

        {!! Form::submit('Send') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

So, comment has the user_id and I have to send it too with form, maybee by this:`$sth->myuserid` but how can I use it in LibraryController?

Additionally, I found this: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/157/creating-a-hidden-input-field is it a good option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden field to store the user id and then retrieve it in your controller:

```
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $user_id) }}
```

But if you are using Auth component you can get the authenticated user by using the Auth facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

...

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Comment: In your form you could add a hidden field like this `{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $sth->sth_id) }}` and then get it in your controller like this: `request()->input('user_id')`

Answer (score 2):

If it's for admin panel or something, you can use hidden input:

```
{!! Form::hidden('user_id', $user->id) !!}
```

But if you want to pass an ID of a current user, do not pass it through a form. Use `auth()->id()` in a controller to get ID.

Comment: It was my idea to use auth facade

Comment: @YouneL excuse me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but what if it isn't auth but something else and I want use it:['LibraryController@sth', $sth->sth_id], how to use it in LibraryController ?